# Is it bad practice to control authorize attributes using constant strings in a public class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, constants, authorize-attribute

I am building a large ASP.NET MVC application.  I need to be able to change user rights and permissions programmatically for individual pieces of the application and am trying to find the best approach to do it.  I started off just using the authorize attribute like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,Moderator")]
```

As the app grew bigger, whenever the client wanted me to make a change to permissions, I would need to go through, find all of the references for that permission set and add and remove roles accordingly.  At first I tracked this using comments, but it quickly grew too cumbersome, so I knew I had to build something that could help me group together roles based on their collective permissions.

I tried to search for solutions or alternative options online but came up short. So, I started writing out my own class to do it for me, and I had to make all of the variables constants so that they could be used within the authorize attribute so my class looks like:

```
public class RoleAccess
    {
        //List of roles
        private const string Coordinator= "Coordinator";
        private const string Moderator = "Moderator";
        private const string ApplicationAdministrator = "AppAdmin";
        private const string allRoles = Coordinator + "," + Moderator + "," + ApplicationAdministrator

        public const string EventsRead = allRoles;
        public const string EventsWrite = ApplicationAdministrator;

        public const string UserInfoRead = Moderator + "," + ApplicationAdministrator;
        public const string UserInfoWrite = ApplicationAdministrator;

public static bool HasAccess(string accessCSV, IPrincipal user)
        {
            List<string> accessList = accessCSV.Split(',').ToList();
            foreach (string role in accessList)
            {
                if (user.IsInRole(role))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And I access the roles using authorize attributes like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = RoleAccess.EventsWrite)]
```

When I am working with permissions within a view (whether or not HTML should be created through razor) I use the HasAccess function like this:

```
@if (RoleAccess.HasAccess(RoleAccess., User))
            {
                <td class="no-sort">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = User.ID })</th>
            }
```

Are there any issues with doing it this way and/or best practices I am not following by taking this approach?  I feel like I am missing something; some issue I will run into down the line if I do it this way.  So I wanted to throw it out there and get some feedback before I use it on any production projects.

Thanks for any advice you can provide!

Comment: Using the constants seems fine. You would have trouble reading the values from config, however; Attribute parameters require the value to be compile-time constant, and you can't achieve that with a value read from config at run-time.

Comment: @JonathonChase, thanks for the quick response.  Oh yeah, that makes sense, that was why I had to use constants in the first place.  I will edit so that the question is more succinct.  Thanks!

Comment: you could also add and implement AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter and load/read values from config file (or load them on Application_Start).